# How to replace nan by dictionary in pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to replace a NaN in a dataframe column by a dictionary like this: `{"value":["100"]}`

```
df[column].apply(type).value_counts()
```

output:

```
<class 'dict'>     11565
<class 'float'>       43


df[column].isna().sum()
```

output => 43

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lambda function for replace by dictionary:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column':[np.nan, {'a':[4,5]}]})

d = {"value":["100"]}
df['column'] = df['column'].apply(lambda x: d if pd.isna(x) else x)
print (df)
               column
0  {'value': ['100']}
1       {'a': [4, 5]}
```

Or list comprehension:

```
df['column'] = [d if pd.isna(x) else x for x in df['column']]
```